# Datepicker doesn't execute when submitted

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have been working on this for days but I don't get it so I decided to ask here. I really have a hard time tracing where is the problem is in my code.. here my code:

```
  $(".editME").click(function(){

      var element = $(this);
      var show = element.attr("id");

      $.get('index.php',{option:'myReports', task: 'edit', id: show},function(data)
      {
          $('body').html(data);
          $("#editFile").show(1000);
      });
      return true;
  });
```

When I click the edit button it while showing the whole page and inside of it I have the plugin `datepicker`. The problem is it doesn't show the calendar:

```
  $(function() {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true
      });
  });
```

When I change the URL to `index.php?option=myReports&task=edit`.. the calendar appears.

My question: how can I load the calendar while I execute the editME?.  Even if I return true it doesn't execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you might be able to use

```
$("#datepicker").live("click", function(){
  $(this).datepicker({ changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
});
```

Read up on the [live() method](http://api.jquery.com/live/). It makes jQuery recognize dynamically generated objects.

Comment: thanks you fast replyed

i dont get the date shown but it takes time to execute.. about 10s to execute.

Comment: And by execute you mean do nothing? The boxes don't show? If so, I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. You might try adding some HTML to your question and seeing where/if you can clarify.

Comment: the box show but intakes time to appear the calendar box. jquery have lots of attitudes :(.. i test the datepicker in google crome it runs fast well in firefox so slow.. 

edit 1 class="editME"
edit 2 class="editME"
edit 3 class="editME"

onclick edit 1.. edit 2 and edit 3 disable.. even if i put 
 
$(".showlogs").live("click",function(){

it doesn't work at all.. :(

Comment: You might try putting that code in your question as an update. I'm not sure I can make sense of it.